# Ruby 2.3.0 gem pg version 0.18.4 install error El Capitan

Tags: ruby, macos, postgresql, rubygems

After "bundle install", I keep getting this error for many times.

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/daisukeishii/tasca-     io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/.gemtest

An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

- `gem install pg` keeps giving the same error
  -ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]
  -psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.0
  -Mac El Capitan
  -I checked all related posts in stackoverflow but could not solve this.
- Tried to uninstall/install PostgreSQL through brew.
- Tried to uninstall/install Ruby

Do you have any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had problems installing the pg gem and for me this did the trick:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

However, looking at your error message it actually seems to be about not having write permissions to the gem directory. Maybe you have tried to install the gem as root with `sudo gem install pg` and it left behind a directory under your home directory having root as owner instead of your regular user.

Remove the directory using:

```
sudo rm -rf /Users/daisukeishii/tascaio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4
```

And then try installing again using the `ARCHFLAGS` above.

Note that your post has some sort of copy paste problem in the path so the path in this example might not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `pg` gem was looking for a PostgreSQL installation in the wrong place, so I runned

`bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5/bin/pg_config`

which was where my PostgreSQL installation actually was, and then

`bundle install`